# Cable or hydraulic clutch on a 2005 Vauxhall Astra

Tags: clutch, vauxhall

Do I have a cable or hydraulic operated clutch in my Vauxhall Astra 1.7 diesel 2005 model?

Answer (score 2):

I thought I knew, but I'm not 100% sure. What you can do is open your bonnet and look at the gearbox. If there's a steel cable operating the clutch mechanism, you have a cable clutch. If it's a solid piece of steel, it's a hydraulic clutch.

If it's not immediately clear where these things are, have someone operate the clutch and gearbox while you have the bonnet open. The things that move will be your clutch and gear mechanisms.

Update: Turns out it's a hydraulic clutch: http://www.astraownersclub.com/vb/showthread.php/694456-Astra-h-1-7-cdti-clutch-fail.